# Run multiple tasks in parallel and cancel rest if any of them returns false .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task, task-parallel-library

Currently I have a code like this:

```
 bool task1Result = await RunTask1(data);
 if(!task1Result)
     return false;

 bool task2Result = await RunTask2(data);
 if(!task2Result)
     return false;

 bool task3Result = await RunTask3(data);
 if(!task3Result)
     return false;

 bool task4Result = await RunTask4(data);
 if(!task4Result)
     return false;
```

Added sample:

```
private async Task<bool> RunListOfTasks() {
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

var tasks = new List<Task<bool>> { RunTask1(data, ct), RunTask2(data, ct), RunTask3(data, ct), RunTask4(data, ct) };
while (tasks.Any())
{
    var currentTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    if (!await currentTask)
    {
        ct.Cancel();
        return false;
    }
    tasks.Remove(currentTask);
}
return true;
}
```

Is it possible to run all of them in parallel and if one of them fails (like result is false), then stop processing the rest and return. Thanks

Comment: Each run task method would need to be changed to be cancellable e.g. by accepting a `CancellationToken`. Then you could use `Task.WhenAll` to parallelise.

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. You don't cancel the tasks, you cancel the actions/jobs that are executed by those tasks. Your methods need to accept a `CancellationToken` parameter and check it to see if cancellation was signalled

Comment: `if one of them fails (like result is false),` that's not what `fail` means. A `false` result means the task succeeded and returned `false`. Failure means that an exception was thrown. You can catch any failure easily if you use a try block around `await Task.WhenAll();` and signal the other methods to cancel through a `CancellationTokenSource`. It's a lot harder to do the same if you have to check every result. You won't be able to use `Task.WhenAll` in that case

Comment: What do those methods really do? Why do they return a `bool` instead of throwing? It matters. If they *have* to return a boolean, you should probably pass a `CancellationTokenSource` to each of them, to allow each task to signal cancellation before returning. Typically, cancellation flows from the outside in

Comment: yes, fail means that the task succeeded and the output of the task is false.

Comment: i have edited and added some sample code. Is it possible to share some sample code

Answer (score 2):

The `Task.WhenAny`-in-a-loop is [generally considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763982/how-to-use-task-whenany-and-implement-retry/43764680#43764680) an antipattern, because of its [O(n²) complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271006/task-whenany-alternative-to-list-avoiding-on%C2%B2-issues). The preferred approach is to wrap your tasks in another set of tasks, that will include the functionality of canceling the `CancellationTokenSource` when the result is `false`. Then `await` the wrapper tasks instead of the initial tasks, and propagate their result.

An easy way to wrap the tasks is the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ operator:

```
private async Task<bool> RunListOfTasks()
{
    using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

    List<Task<bool>> tasks = new()
    {
        RunTask1(data, cts.Token),
        RunTask2(data, cts.Token),
        RunTask3(data, cts.Token),
        RunTask4(data, cts.Token),
    };

    Task<bool>[] enhancedTasks = tasks.Select(async task =>
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!result) cts.Cancel();
            return result;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) when (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }).ToArray();

    bool[] results = await Task.WhenAll(enhancedTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return results.All(x => x);
}
```

Comment: Very nice mini setup.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework does this in a very nice way:

```
bool[] result =
    await 
        Observable
            .Merge(
                Observable.FromAsync(ct => RunTask1(data, ct)),
                Observable.FromAsync(ct => RunTask2(data, ct)),
                Observable.FromAsync(ct => RunTask3(data, ct)),
                Observable.FromAsync(ct => RunTask4(data, ct)))
            .TakeUntil(x => x == false)
            .ToArray();
```

It returns all of the results that come in right up to the point one of the tasks returns a `false`.

Comment: This is a decent solution, with the caveat that the `await` might return before all started `RunTaskX` operations have completed. In other words it allows fire-and-forget to occur. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901276/how-to-implement-a-custom-selectmany-operator-that-waits-for-all-observable-subs "How to implement a custom SelectMany operator that waits for all observable subsequences to complete?") is a question related to this issue.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - No, depending on how each task is implemented, the fact that the observable stops, then the tasks stop proactively.

Comment: Do you mean that fire-and-forget is impossible with the answer above? I am just claiming is that fire-and-forget is possible, not that it will happen always. And depending on the scenario, fire-and-forget might be anything from OK to unacceptable.

Comment: It depends on how you write the task methods as to if they fire and forget or if they terminate.

Comment: True. So if you have a scenario that makes fire-and-forget unacceptable, and you don't know with 100% certainty that all the asynchronous methods that you are calling are reacting instantaneously to a cancellation signal, then the above solution is not appropriate.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Sure. If you say so. Time and money is usually the thing. If you have enough then anything can be done.

Comment: I think that it's more of a case of choosing the right tool for the job. If you choose the wrong tool, the mistake can be expensive.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Sure, are you saying Rx is the wrong tool or is it TPL?

Comment: Unless I knew for sure that fire-and-forget is harmless for my scenario, I would stay away from Rx for solving this problem. TBH I would avoid the Rx in all scenarios because I have a personal aversion for fire-and-forget in general. And it's not that using Rx results to a significantly more readable code. A `Task.WhenAll`-based or `Parallel.ForEachAsync`-based solution is pretty compact anyway, not to mention that it doesn't require a dependency to a NuGet package, and it has a smoother learning curve.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Save Rx for the priesthood...

Comment: A simple `.ContinueWith(t=>{ if (t.IsCompletedSuccesfully &&  !t.Result) cts.Cancel();})` for each task would be cheaper - no observables and scheduling, no state machine allocations. The operation doesn't block so it doesn't really matter where the continuation runs but `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` can be used to ensure the continuation runs asynchronously. `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` could be used to ensure exceptions aren't swallowed