# How to run multi threads in a sequence without tracking or knowing if there any threads existing before starting a new thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, threadpool

I have a situation where my program performs these two tasks

1. Fetch data via ODBC for 96 tables one after the other.
   a. Create insert commands sql file.
   b. Execute the inserts-script via SqlCmd command line utility.

I need to enhance this process so as I can utilize the full potential of the CPU via multi-threading

The ideal solution I am trying to implement is as such. The main thread will keep fetching the data via ODBC where as upon each table's data is fetched and stored in a file on disk the main thread then initiates a new Process of SqlCMD utility which inserts the data into SQL server and the main thread goes on to fetching the next table via ODBC.

The problem or the goal that I want to achieve is that I want to make sure that the new Process of SqlCmd start in a queue/sequence only when the prior processese of SqlCMD are finished

**This method of exportOdbcToSQLDB is called in an outer loop 96 times**.

```
private void exportOdbcToSQLDB(string tableName, SqlConnection sqlCon, OdbcConnection odbcCon)
 {
     InsertAndValidate insertValidateObj = new InsertAndValidate();
     insertValidateObj.sqlCon = sqlCon;
     insertValidateObj.odcConnection = odbcCon;
     insertValidateObj.logTableName = "_Log";

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
         return;
     String columns = "";
     string tmpSelect = "SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "]";
     using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(tmpSelect, sqlCon))
     using (var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
     {
         columns = builder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText;
         columns = columns.Split(new String[] { ")" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
         columns = columns.Split(new String[] { "(" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
         columns = columns.Trim();
         Application.DoEvents();
     }

     int totalCount = 0;
     DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
     string strInsert = "";
     System.IO.File.WriteAllText("sql_" + tableName + ".sql", "");

     string tableFilePath = Path.Combine(Config.qbTablesDir, tableName + ".sql");
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tableFilePath, true))
     {
         writer.WriteLine("SET NOCOUNT ON" + Helper1.Go());
         writer.Write("Update _Log set Remarks  = Concat(Remarks, '| Insert Start time ',dbo.dNow())" + Helper1.Go());
         string insertTemp = "Insert into [" + tableName + "] (" + columns + ") Values ";
         string queryString = @"select " + columns + " from [" + tableName + "]";

         insertValidateObj.addTableState(tableName);
         insertValidateObj.ResetStats(tableName);
         Application.DoEvents();

         OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, insertValidateObj.odcConnection);
         using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             int colCount = reader.FieldCount;
             if (reader.HasRows)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     while (reader.Read())
                     {
                         totalCount++;
                         writer.Write(insertTemp + this.GenerateInsert(reader, tableName, columns) + Helper1.Go());
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     string exception1 = (String.Concat("Row ", totalCount, ex.ToString()));
                 }
                 Application.DoEvents();
             }
             insertTemp = "Update _Log set Remarks  = Concat(Remarks, '| Insert End time ',dbo.dNow())" + Helper1.Go();
             insertTemp = "Update _log set SuccessRecords = (Select count(1) from [" + tableName + "]) where TableName = '" + tableName + "'" + Helper1.Go();
             writer.Write(insertTemp);
         }
     }
     DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
     insertValidateObj.SetStats(tableName, totalCount, 0, 0, startTime, endTime);

     if (totalCount > 0)
     {
         tablesToInsert.Enqueue(tableName);
         ExecuteQbInserts(tableName);
     }
 }
```

**This method is called in the above method**

```
public static void ExecuteQbInserts(string tableName)
 {
     string tmpPathInput = Path.Combine(Config.qbTablesDir, tableName + ".sql");
     string tmpPathOutput = Path.Combine(Config.qbSqlInsertsLogsDir, tableName + "_log.txt");

     string command = string.Concat("sqlcmd -S . -d qb", Config.ClientName, " -U sa -P atiqf -i \"", tmpPathInput, "\" -o \"", tmpPathOutput, "\"");
     ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
     processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
     processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     Process.Start(processInfo);
 }
```

**Result:**

Multiple SqlCMD processes runs when the rate of sqlCmd inserts is less than the rate at which the main thread fetches the ODBC data.

Solution required:
Have the the main thread keeps getting data of 96 tables at its own rate and have sqlCMD processes run one after the other.

Comment: As it stands your question is asking too much, what specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Why not have a queue of data retrieved and a permanent second thread which monitors the queue - in fact you can flag to the thread every time you add a new table so that it doesn't have to poll.

Comment: Sounds like you want some pipeline behavior and may be interested in TPL DataFlow.

Comment: Are you running the `exportOdbcToSQLDB` on the UI thread? Is the `Application.DoEvents` intended for keeping the UI responsive?

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7? .NET Framework?

Comment: Sounds like you should actually be using `SqlConnection` and perhaps even `SqlBulkCopy` or similar, which would significantly speed up this bulk insert.

Comment: @Kale K, If i had asked one line question, then you would have said that you have provided very less information or examples. Instead i have provided all i could. I am stuck on a problem of How to execute Multi Threads and each of such thread should run when the prior thread is finished. where as I can't use thread.join() because the child/multi-threads are not pre-define the threads, the threads are created upon data is fetched in the main thread via odbc for each table.

Comment: @Kale K, I do not want to use Queues can't work unless i use a lock on queue when working on the queues in the multi-thread and locking the queue will lock it for all the threads even the main thread which will defiy the purpose of utilizing the multithreading and it will behave just like all operations are running in single queue.

Comment: @TPL DataFlow, Yes I am using the ``exportOdbcToSQLDB`` on the UI thread and ``Application.DoEvents`` is intended to keep the UI thread Alive only very rarely using it so that i can update the logs to the text box. See it doesn't make any difference if i use the ``exportOdbcToSQLDB`` on the UI thread or run it in a console app or run it in a background worker. at the end every thing works under one Process / exe / console.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias I am running it in .NET Framework. Thank you.

Comment: @Charlieface
Thank you for suggesting alternate solution ``SqlBulkCopy`` which is an over a different stragegy. My ODBC source is not 100% compliant to the data columns in the source database tables. As such, i tried the ``SqlBulkCopy`` and it was not successfull. By the way my ODBC driver is actually QODBC  aka QuickBooks desktop version.

Comment: You could probably still do it in a streaming fashion if you either do a custom `SELECT` for the reading half, or you create your own datareader (much more complex).

Comment: @Charlieface, the ODBC driver by Quickbooks already reads the data in streaming fashion i think, it reads the data in chunks and we can control the chunk size. the issue is not about insreasing the reading spead of ODBC faster, its already to its max depending upon the spead of Ram and Processor cores. but i will try actually running the odbcDataReader in multi-threads to see if that ODBC driver will fetch data for multiple tables concurently.

Comment: My point is you shouldn't need to mess around with saving SQL files and running them. With SqlBulkCopy you can stream the data straight from one server to the other directly.

Comment: Hell no! Never ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. If you have to do that to make your code work then you are setting yourself up for a lot of pain.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a sufficient solution to your problem would be to parallelize the `ExportOdbcToSQLDB` and `ExecuteQbInserts` in this way: The `ExportOdbcToSQLDB` for the table `i` will be executed in parallel with the `ExecuteQbInserts` for the table `i - 1`. Assuming that one of the two operations is consistently slower than the other, the total amount of time for processing all tables will be equal with the sum of the slower operation. The faster operation will travel by hitchhiking, so to say, without affecting the total execution time.

The `ParallelizeTwoActions` method below implements this scheme in an abstract generic way:

```
/// <remarks>
/// Invokes two actions for each element in the source sequence, sequentially.
/// The action1 is invoked sequentially for one element at a time.
/// The action2 is also invoked sequentially for one element at a time.
/// The action1 for an element is invoked in parallel with the action2 for its
/// previous element.
/// </remarks>
public static async Task ParallelizeTwoActions<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Action<TSource> action1, Action<TSource> action2)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action1);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(action2);

    Task task1 = Task.CompletedTask;
    Task task2 = Task.CompletedTask;
    try
    {
        foreach (TSource item in source)
        {
            task1 = Task.Run(() => action1(item));
            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
            task2 = Task.Run(() => action2(item));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The marble diagram below illustrates how the `action1` and `action2` are invoked for six elements A, B, C, D, E and F.

```
action1: A------| B----------| C-----|    D---------| E-------| F-------|
action2:          A----|       B--------| C---|       D----|    E----|    F----|
```

Notice how the `action1(B)` overlaps with the `action2(A)`.

You could use the `ParallelizeTwoActions` like this:

```
private async void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        btnExecute.Enabled = false;

        await ParallelizeTwoActions(tableNames, tableName =>
        {
            ExportOdbcToSQLDB(tableName, sqlCon, odbcCon);
        }, tableName =>
        {
            ExecuteQbInserts(tableName);
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        btnExecute.Enabled = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

For this to work, you must do a change at the bottom of the `ExecuteQbInserts`:

```
Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit(); /* Block the current thread until the process terminates */
```

You must also remove all the `Application.DoEvents();` lines, because both the `ExportOdbcToSQLDB` and the `ExecuteQbInserts` will be invoked on [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) threads. You should avoid any interaction with UI controls inside these methods. It is strictly forbidden to interact with UI controls from any thread other than the UI thread.

In case you are not familiar with [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)/[`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await), you might want to read some tutorials, like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios) or [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). It's a really great way to keep your UI responsive by offloading work to background threads, without complicating your code with manual `Thread` management, or with awkward `BackgroundWorker`s etc.

Comment: Thank you for writing a solution to the question @Theodor Zoulias. I really appreciate. The solution you are proposing will cause my ODBC data extraction to run in multi-thread and i haven't yet tested if the ODBC driver will support or allow me to run concurent DataReaders via multi-threads. I will give it a try and will let you know.

Comment: the framework provides ways of interacting with the UI controls why still you are forbading to use ?  UI controls are accessed via delegates like   `` delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                form.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.txtLog.AppendText(text);
            }
        }`` so what could go wrong.

Comment: as far as I have experienced multi-thread programming, all sub threads still depends or referr back to the Main thread of the PROCESS who started those as long as we are starting those multi-threads in one program. The best alternate to avoide at all using the UI in other threads will be to desing the software soultion that involves multiple EXE / PROCESS / CONSOLE apps which communicate via WinProc SendMessage strategry.

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman the technique in this answer will invoke the `ExportOdbcToSQLDB` method on thread-pool threads, but only one invocation will be active at a time. The invocations are sequential, not concurrent. Your ODBC driver shouldn't have any problem, unless it is thread-affine, which would be something unusual. You could give this solution a try, and report your observations.

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman I added XML comments above the `ParallelizeTwoActions` method, and a marble diagram that demonstrates its behavior.

Comment: @AtiqUrRehman it is OK to schedule interactions with UI controls using the [`Control.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke)/[`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) APIs. What is not OK is to interact with UI controls directly.

Comment: your expalanations make sense. I will give it a try and update.