# How to run parallel operations on set of files?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

So I'm trying to run parallel operations on a set of files using C#.

The first operation converts the file type and stores it in a temporary folder. The second operation does some processing to the converted files

I want the second operation to run in parallel and process the files as they are being converted. Anybody have any hints on the best way to do this? I'm new to parallel programming.

So far, I've looked into using TPL (task parallel library) and threading. I'm getting caught up because I'm not sure what the best way is to have the second operation monitor the files being converted, and to make sure the first operation has been completed before finishing.

Comment: Specify the .NET version you're targeting, the tools available can change quite a bit. For example, see the [Channel<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) class and its `ChannelWriter` / `ChannelReader` ([ChannelReader<T>.WaitToReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.waittoreadasync))

Comment: I have posted recently a [`ParallelizeTwoActions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77074489/11178549) method as a solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074222/how-to-run-multi-threads-in-a-sequence-without-tracking-or-knowing-if-there-any "How to run multi threads in a sequence without tracking or knowing if there any threads existing before starting a new thread"), that might solve your problem too.

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) is what you're looking for. Watch for new files then kick of [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) to process the file.

Comment: I don't think you need ^^FSW. I'd actually have a look into [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) and create a pipeline for that. It has a learning curve but I have used it for exactly that kind of task and fell in love (yes, we also fought. No relationship is without troubles). You _can_ handcraft a pipeline using Channels, though. Don't know if that would actually be easier. Back in the day, I didn't have them.

Comment: @Fildor for a couple of years I would also recommend the TPL Dataflow for creating pipelines, until I realized that it is [fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603428/tpl-dataflow-exception-in-transform-block-with-bounded-capacity/69209696#69209696 "TPL Dataflow exception in transform block with bounded capacity"), with no hope to be fixed any time soon. Its components are too loosely connected to each other. It's also remarkably difficult to extend. To write a custom block you have to implement weird interfaces, with sparse instructions for how to implement them.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'll have a look into that. Sounds horrific ... meanwhile, I was thinking about something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oabeRU

Comment: All _I_ can say about it is that it mostly did what I wanted and expected. When I started using it, I had some misconceptions about its inner workings, of course. But I consider that a me-problem, not a Dataflow-problem.

Comment: @Fildor regarding the [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oabeRU), yes, you could try to patch the library and work around its problems, but ideally a tool should help you solve your problems, not augment them. If 50% of the code is patching the tool, you are using a bad tool. That's how I see it. The TPL Dataflow was designed/intended for making complex dataflow meshes, not simple straightforward pipelines. Creating a pipeline should be simple, like PLINQ. The TPL Dataflow makes this simple thing difficult, imperfect, verbose and unreliable.

Comment: @Fildor the icing in the cake, in case the delegate throws an `OperationCanceledException`, this error is suppressed. Microsoft says it's [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619 "Dataflow TransformBlock silently fails if TaskCanceledException is thrown"), meaning it's a bug that they decided to not address, because fixing it could break existing code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am not disagreeing. All I am saying is, _in the past_, for the requirements I had (which _was_ a fairly simple pipeline, comaparable to the one in this question), I found it to be reliable _enough_ and that tad more convenient than coding all of it from scratch ... I _do see_ your points, though.

Comment: @Fildor sure, what happened in the past belongs to the past. No need to worry for an one-use migration console app that ran years ago and did its job. But for new development, especially for long-life applications that are doing anything serious, the TPL Dataflow is no longer my tool of choice. Not that I am aware of a perfect alternative to be honest.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, that would have been my next consideration: What to replace it with? I think I _could_ try and use Channels, maybe some Rx-Stuff ... would depend on the requirements, I guess.

Comment: @Fildor for me Rx is dead too. Not only for making pipelines, but it is especially bad for pipelines because it doesn't support backpressure and it [leaks fire-and-forget tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901276/how-to-implement-a-custom-selectmany-operator-that-waits-for-all-observable-subs) by default. What **I** would use as substitute is simple home-made improvised tools like the `ParallelizeTwoActions` that I mentioned earlier. Until something really good appears in the horizon.